# When i run selenium webdriver code Firefox webdriver not starting through given webaddress

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When i tried to start on Firefox web driver its not starting its showing firefox default page

```
    WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
    dr.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    dr.manage().window().maximize();
```

its not starting its showing firefox default page
Below i attach output image screenshot

[https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/43.0.4/firstrun/learnmore/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWPo.png)

Comment: which webdriver version you are using? 2.48.2?

Comment: try with lower firefox version

Comment: I had the same problem several days ago and it's because of the version of Firefox you have installed. Just install a previous version and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. The solution to this problem is to update the selenium version. When the page u mentioned i.e https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/43.0.4/firstrun/learnmore/ opens on firefox launch go to Options -> Addons -> Extensions. You will be able to see the Error there. I got "Forefox Webdriver could not be loaded and is disabled".

This was on Firefox 43 with selenium 2.44. Updating to selenium 2.51 rectified the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is one of the most compatible browsers with selemium, and at the same time, is one of the least compatible.

I say this because if you do not have the correct version of the selenium library to go with the version of firefox you are running, or vice-versa, it will always fail.

I would start by attempting to switch to a different version of Firefox.  Selenium version 2.48.0 supports Firefox versions 24-41, so if your firefox version does not fit within that range, it is more than likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot comment yet but I would like to help. I got the similar issue when I used selenium webdriver integrated in my python script. The problem was with credentials (particularly with the SSL protocols while declaring a new webdriver object). The code I used looked as the following:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = "/opt/local/bin/phantomjs", service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
```

As you can see I use a key that **ignores ssl errors**. This solved my issue, so I am not sure what platform you use to write the code but hope you can find the similar call for the object.

I found the way how people handle untrusted certificates [here](http://learn-automation.com/handle-untrusted-certificate-selenium/). Particularly, for FireFox:

```
//It creates firefox profile
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();

// This will set the true value
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

// This will open  firefox browser using above created profile
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("pass the url as per your requirement");
```

Hope it helps you!

Best.
-Petr.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. This will resolve the issue..

```
    FirefoxProfile fpi = new FirefoxProfile();
    fpi.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
    fpi.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", "about:blank");
    wd = new FirefoxDriver(fpi);
    wd.get("http://www.google.com");
```

if you want to over-ride the properties of firefox, then,
1.first to find the list of browser properties, type "about:config" in the address url
2.use, setPreference method to set/assign the values..